# gvim to show file path in all the tabs (even current one)

Tags: vim, tabs

By default shows gvim in my tabs: the names of files. They're however shown in a way like this:

- if is in the same as the currently opened tab/buffer => no path shown (only file name)
- otherwise abbreviated path and file name are shown

however when I change the tab this causes tab names to change and brings me quite some confusion.

Any chance to have it constantly going for: abbreviated path and file name are shown?

I've seen following:

```
:set guitablabel=%!expand(\"\%:t\")
```

however it goes the other way, so shows only file names on all the tabs (no path at all).

in http://objectmix.com/editors/148913-display-gvim-tabs.html

Comment: Did you read `:help setting-guitablabel` and `:help statusline`?

Comment: @romainl I read it, still, didn't find the way

Comment: @cirosantilli I wanted abbrevated path in all the tabs (including current one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
:set guitablabel=%!pathshorten(expand(\"\%:p\"))
```

This uses the `:p` *filename-modifier* to get the full absolute path, and then shortens the path via `pathshorten()` in the way it is usually done in the tab labels.

Comment: thanks, that does the job! will mark as correct once I'm allowed by stackoverflow

Comment: any chance to keep all other behaviour of tab available? like `+` on modified and unsaved buffer?

Comment: Once you have a custom one, you need to emulate the default functionality. But `:help setting-guitablabel` (which you really should have read by now!) has example code how to add it back.